# How to get text value by pressing enter on keyboard without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, dom-events

I am trying to implement a textbox which when press on enter on keyboard but will not automatically submit the form. This textbox is inside a form:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID, new { @class = "form-control 
input-sm", placeholder = "Enter Id", 
onkeypress = "return fncValidateMemberID(event);" })
```

This is the Javascript code:

```
 function fncValidateMemberID(e) {
       
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            //My AJAX logic here but I cannot get the text value I inputted on my textbox
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The problem with my Javascript code is I cannot get text value.

Comment: what do you see if you add in `alert($("#ID").value());` to your function within the if statement?

Comment: Thanks for that, I already got it, you can put your comment as post, then I will mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
function fncValidateMemberID(e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        alert($("#ID").val());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

It should alert the value of your text input.

Comment: If you are using jQuery, it should be: `alert($("#ID").val());` (not `.value()`).

Answer (score 1):

Pass the element to your handler function, and then you'll be able to get its value:

```
onkeypress = "return fncValidateMemberID(event, this);"


function fncValidateMemberID(e, textbox) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        var text = textbox.value;
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you've tagged the question with jQuery, you can get the value of the text field with the `.val()` method, as in the following (replace `ID` with your textbox's `clientID`):

```
var text = $("#ID").val();
```

Or, without jQuery (vanilla JavaScript):

```
var text = document.getElementById("ID").value;
```